# Most efficient way to concat Vectors

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the most efficient way to insert one Vector into another at specific position?

For example:

```
var aa:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([1, 2, 3]);
var bb:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([9, 8, 7]);
```

This doesn't seems to work:

```
bb.splice(1, 0, aa);
```

The result is [9, 0, 8, 7].

Answer (score 1):

For the moment there is no builtin function other than doing a loop over the `Vector`, here two methods (i have not timed them).

If bb can be a new `Vector` you can do for example:

```
var insertIndex:int = 1;
bb=bb.slice(0, insertIndex).concat(aa).concat(bb.slice(insertIndex));
```

If bb cannot be change you can do a `splice` but with preparing the elements to insert into a new `Array`:

```
var insertIndex:int = 1;

var parms:Array=[insertIndex, 0]; // prepare the arguments for the splice call
var j:int = 2; // length of the parms array

var len:int = aa.length;

for (var i:int = 0; i < len; i++, j++){
    parms[j] = aa[i];
}

// call the splice with the new arguments
bb.splice.apply(bb, parms);
```

Comment: I think concat does a loop behind the hood, so the two solutions should be roughly equivalient performance wise.

Comment: Looks like slice.concat.concat is the most efficient so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to concat one after the other, as PatrickS mentionned bb.concat will do the job.

If you need to insert values in the middle you'll need something like

```
for each (var i : int in aa.reverse())
{
    bb.splice(1,0,i);
}
```

or, more elegantly, this, if you cannot change aa

```
var insertingIndex : int = 2;
for each ( var i : int in aa )
{
    bb.splice( insertingIndex, 0, i );
    insertingIndex++;
}
```

Comment: For this loop what is variable "i" for?

Comment: None of 2 examples are working and none of two examples are efficient. I still hope to find more efficient way then loop and splice.